# How to set Cookies in alamofire?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

How to set Cookies in **Alamofire** such that such that every time I kill the app and restart it, the same cookie is sent?

Comment: Share your source code you've tried for this

Comment: Dear Gaurav, I faced same problem, did you find any helpful solution?

Answer (score 11):

## Swift 5.1 & Alamofire 5.0

Prepare your cookies

```swift
let cookieProps = [
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: "##put your domain here##",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: "/",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: "##put your cookie key here##",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: "##put your cookie value here##"
   ]
```

Set your cookies

```swift
if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps) {
    AF.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(cookie)
}
```

After that, you can do your normal request and the cookies will be sent to server

```swift
Alamofire.request(
  ##URL##,
  method: ##.post or .get##,
  parameters: parameters
  ).responseString {
    response in 
    ....
}
```

Comment: will the cookie be sent over even if domain of the url changes? in my case, i have to use a different domain for downloading larger files

Answer (score 6):

Get cookies from response using the `NSHTTPCookie` [cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(_:forURL:)] method.

```
// setCookies
 func setCookies(cookies: NSHTTPCookie){
     Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, forURL: response.URL!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
 }

// getCookies
func getCookies() {
    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://test.com/test", parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
        if let
            header = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: String],
            URL = response.request?.URL
        {
            let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(header, forURL: URL)
            print(cookies)
        }
    }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
func setCookies(cookies: HTTPCookie){
    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, forURL: URL, mainDocumentURL: nil)
}

Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters).responseData { (responseObject) -> Void in

                if let resposecode = responseObject.response?.statusCode {
                    if resposecode != 200 {
                        // error
                    } else {
                        // view all cookies
                        print(HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies)
                    }
                }
           }
```

Comment: I want to set a default cookie every time I make a request, even when I close and restart the app, the cookie should be same. This was not I was looking for.

Comment: @krunal How does it store the cookie persistently, if it does?

Comment: With every response, you need to get cookies, store in permanent/default storage (called NSUserDefaults). With every request get cookies from permanent storage and set with request.

Comment: Is there an inbuilt way to manage this? Sort of a loadable session or something similar?

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: response.allHeaderFields , for: response.URL!)

Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, forURL: URL, mainDocumentURL: nil)
```

Alamofire instance is shared singleton, so for all Request the cookie is set.
Hope it's works for you.

Comment: is this for one single url or all the url request I'll hit through Alamofire?

Comment: can i know the reason for down voting?

Comment: Can you help to update latest Alamofire code changes?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
let httpCookie = HTTPCookie.init(properties:
        [HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version : "0",
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name : "MYTestID",
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value : "983724dd3dea4924b8d675b0df08b611",
        HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires : "2027-05-13 09:21:23 +0000"])
    if let cookie = httpCookie {
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
    }
```

Comment: will this cookie be stored even after app restarts?

Comment: You can reload this in Appdelegate at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @Tony Hello, How is that possible to restore them in app delegate? please show me some code

Answer (score 0):

```
if let fields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String : String]{
            let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: fields, for: (response.request?.url!)!)
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: (response.request?.url!)!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
        }
```