# Set alamofire cookies permenantly

Tags: swift, cookies, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for my requests and I get cookies in some of them, everything works fine when I launch the app and use it but when I kill the app and reopen the cookies are not there anymore. I searched a lot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976688/how-to-set-cookies-in-alamofire/43977128#43977128) but none of the answers helped.
I try to save the cookies after each request and load them before sending request as below:

```
    func saveCookies(response: DataResponse<Any>) {
    let headerFields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as! [String: String]
    let url = response.response?.url
    let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: url!)
    var cookieArray = [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]]()
    for cookie in cookies {
        cookieArray.append(cookie.properties!)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(cookieArray, forKey: "savedCookies")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

func loadCookies() {
    guard let cookieArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "savedCookies") as? [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]] else { return }
    for cookieProperties in cookieArray {
        if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties) {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}
```

But still when I kill the app, I can't get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your cookies in UserDefaults like this:

```
var authToken: String {
    get {
        return defaults.value(forKey: TOKEN_KEY) as! String
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: TOKEN_KEY)
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how I should set it to be my alamofire cookie?

Comment: Just make common request with Alamofire, get an answer from your server and save it to UserDefaults variable. After that, you can reopen your app and use this for all stuff you need.